# Qt _USE_MATH_DEFINES

Tags: c++, qt, openmesh

I need to work with OpenMesh on my PC with Qt IDE, the snip of the simple *.pro file looks like:

```
DEFINES += _USE_MATH_DEFINES
DEFINES += NOMINMAX
#DEFINES += OM_STATIC_BUILD
#OpenMesh
INCLUDEPATH += "D:/Libraries/OpenMesh 6.3/include"
#Debug
LIBS += "D:/Libraries/OpenMesh 6.3/lib/OpenMeshCored.lib"
LIBS += "D:/Libraries/OpenMesh 6.3/lib/OpenMeshToolsd.lib"
# Release
LIBS += "D:/Libraries/OpenMesh 6.3/lib/OpenMeshCore.lib"
LIBS += "D:/Libraries/OpenMesh 6.3/lib/OpenMeshTools.lib"
```

However, I still got the error message: "***C1189: #error:  "You have to define _USE_MATH_DEFINES in the compiler settings!***"
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Plus, I also try to add "#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES" at the top of the 'compiler.hh' file in which the error appear. Then, the error message will disappear in building. But, the program will crash once I run it.

Comment: These problems gone away when i used vs2015 with qt plugin. And I also set _USE_MATH_DEFINES and  NOMINMAX in vs2015 IDE.

Answer (score 2):

if you wanna run your application from Qt creator for any reason as using qmake, you just have to add `"DEFINES += _USE_MATH_DEFINES"` to your *.pro file

Answer (score 0):

The same error occured to me, but with MSVC 2019 16.6.1

Adding the define _USE_MATH_DEFINES in front of my OpenMesh include statement solves the problem for me.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <OpenMesh/Core/Mesh/PolyMesh_ArrayKernelT.hh>
```

The forum Post [How does #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES work?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/102410/) helped me to understand the functionality behind the define.

Comment: In my case, for OpenMesh, I commented the line throwing the error "You have to define _USE_MATH_DEFINES in the compiler settings!" in `compiler.hh` file.